# Disable scroll indicator in all tableview / collectionview

Tags: ios, swift

If I want to disable the scroll indicator in all `tableview` and `collectionview`, what minimum changes do I need to make?

Suppose, I have 50 `tableviews` in my project, I don't want to set the property below in all of them or make changes to so many storyboards.

```swift
self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Basically, I need to mutate a property of an object **in one place only** that will be reflected in all its instances or child inheriting it.

**More context:**

- I tried `protocol with default implementation` but I need to call it somewhere anyway. Is there a hook that gets called every time an object in swift is instantiated for a particular class where I can attach some function or execution block that mutates those properties?
- Maybe javascript `object prototype mutation` is something similar to what I am looking for, which has an adverse performance impact at the time of mutation, and in subsequent execution. What is the performance penalty for similar things (if exist) in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following snippet in `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` depending on what you have:

```
 UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
 UITableView.appearance().showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score -1):

You can subclass a UITableView and use that class everywhere instead of default one.

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }
}
```

Now use this class everywhere. If you create tableview in storyboard, set its class to MyTableView.

Comment: Obviously, I can. But in all storyboards and instances, it needs to be replaced. Something I wanted to avoid. I want it to be configurable from one place only.